# i installed my device with preyproject

Tags: windows, ios

if the device is reformatted and loaded with a new OS after it is stolen, can prey still find the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Prey is a purely software-based tracking program, so if someone formats the hard drive all traces of Prey will be removed.